# How does one correctly format the atoi function?

Tags: c, cs50, atoi

I'm trying to acquaint myself with the atoi function, so I wrote a basic programme using it, but I'm having some problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("String:");
    int i = get_int("Integer:");
    int a = atoi(s[1]);
    int j = i + a;
    
    printf("%i\n", j);
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get the error message `"incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]"`. This seems to suggest that it wants something to do with a `char`, but from what I've read, I was under the impression that atoi was used with strings. If someone could explain where I'm going wrong, I'd be very thankful

Comment: Try `atoi(s);`.  Tip: research `strtol()` for better code than `atoi()` which lacks error handling.

Comment: not sure what is `string s` , if `string` is `char*` , then your `atoi` function should be called as `atoi(s)`

Comment: I suspect `<cs50.h>` hides a `typedef char * string` or the like.  Although well intentioned, I see it as creating confusion like this.  BlueKhakis, I suggest coding `char *s = get_string("String:");`.

Comment: Hi @chux-ReinstateMonica, I replaced my line 7 with the one you suggested, but still receive the same error message. Any idea why?

Comment: @BlueKhakis Yes, the below answer also needs to be applied.

Comment: regarding:: `int a = atoi(s[1]);`  in C, array offsets begin with 0, not 1  So this is actually trying to access the second character in the array `s[]` rather than the first character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `char`(assuming string is a typedef for `char*`) by indexing the string and it wants you to pass a `char*`. So just pass the full string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    string s = get_string("String:");
    int i = get_int("Integer:");
    int a = atoi(s);
    int j = i + a;
    
    printf("%i\n", j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the syntax for `atoi()`

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

Notice the parameter is a pointer, not a single character.

However, the posted code has:

```
int a = atoi(s[1]);
```

which is a single character, not a pointer

suggest:

```
int a = atoi( s );
```

Also, the function: `atoi()`  has no facility to let the program know when an error occurred.  Suggest using the `strtol()`  function which does have a facility to indicate when an error occurred